What Is The Equivalent of Azure B2C ClaimsResolvers When Using Entra External ID
I currently use Azure B2C and I am looking into the new Entra External ID product as a replacement. One of my use cases requires extracting parameters from the call to Azure B2C's authz endpoint, and using it within custom policy for different things. As examples,

I can have the devs pass a &domain_hint=abc.com in the /authorize call so as to be able to activate the equivalent external OIDC claims provider within custom policy using the metadata keys like ClaimValueOnWhichToEnable & ClaimTypeOnWhichToEnable.
Or I can use the redirect uri passed in the /authorize call as input to a REST Technical profile, which calls a token enrichment API that utilizes this input claim as a means to query a backend database, and return claims.

My question is: how can you achieve the same with Entra External ID?

Entra External ID does not support custom policies, and so has no concept of claims resolvers.
There are some API calls that are triggered by events.
The plan is to extend these events over time.
You can also augment claims with native auth.

Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-extension-attribute-collection

Thank you for your response. I have seen these and am currently testing them, but they do not answer the use case where the application can pass a parameter in the request to the IdP (EEID) right at the time the user journey starts. With Azure B2C this is possible and customers have developed a lot based on this. Another example will be loading different custom UI based on a brandindID parameter that can be used in the file path where UI files are loaded from to dynamically load a different UI each time.
